# C++ template; partial specialization implementation

Tags: c++, templates

Given a template class with a single parameter, I can define an implementation for a specific specialization:

```
template<int N>
struct Foo {
    Foo( );
};

Foo<2>::Foo( ) { //works (on MS Visual 2012, even though it's not the most correct form)
}
```

For a multiple parameter template, is it possible to define an implementation for a partial specialization?

```
template <class X, int N>
struct Bar {
    Bar( );
};

template <class X>
Bar<X,2>::Bar( ) { //error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For partial specializations, you need to first define the specialization of the class template itself before you can go defining its members:

```
template <class X, int N>
struct Bar {
    Bar();
};

template<class X>
struct Bar<X,2> {
    Bar();
};

template <class X>
Bar<X,2>::Bar( ) { }
```

The correct form for the first one that you said it works is:

```
template<int N>
struct Foo {
    Foo( );
};

template<>
Foo<2>::Foo( ) { //works
}
```

Comment: Note that the obvious implication is that any code that is common in the partial specialization needs to be duplicated (or moved to a base abusing inheritance). Specializations of types generate unrelated types --which is different than specializations of member functions.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And if I'm not mistaken, this can't be avoided, right?

Comment: correct, not critizising the answer, just stating how the best you can do differs from what he wants to get done

Comment: Thanks ... was afraid of that (having to use inheritance ...). In practice I'm just going with

`if (N == 2) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specialize the class itself before specializing its members. So

```
template <class X, int N>
struct Bar {
    Bar();
};
template<class X>
struct Bar<X,2> {
    Bar();
};
template<class X>
Bar<X,2>::Bar( ) 
{ //error gone
}
```

And you may further specialize your constructor as:

```
template<>
Bar<int,2>::Bar( ) 
{ //error gone
}
```